# Setting ng-model value dynamically to the value of js variable in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ngmodel, angularjs-ng-model

Similar questions have bee asked before and I have tried solutions given to them, but my problem is little different.

Lets say I have an array of objects like this in my controller

```
$scope.objArray = [
  {
    id:1,
    name:"placeholder1"
  },
  {
    id:2,
    name:"placeholder2"
  }
];
```

now based on this array I am generating a form dynamically like this

```
  <div ng-repeat="field in fields">
    {{field.field_name}} </br>
    <input type="text" ng-model="field.field_name"><br>
  </div>
```

here in this form i want `ng-model` value to be set as `placeholder1` and `placeholder2` and not like `javascript` variable like `field.field_name` because my targets are coming from another source which contains html like below.

```
<p>this is sample html {{placeholder1}}. again sample html {{placeholder2}} </p>
```

i don't have those JS variables in here. I could not find any solution which will work this way for me so far.

here is link to plunk:
http://plnkr.co/edit/ttaq0l3PDRu4piwSluUX?p=preview

Comment: Please provide a minimal working example either here (using the code snippet functionality) or on jsFiddle, Plunker, etc. It's not really clear where your variables are coming from, so your question is impossible to answer as it stands right now.

Comment: @Agop added link to plunk

Comment: I dont really understand what you're asking...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case it will look like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="field in fields">
    {{field.field_name}}
    <br>
    <input type="text" ng-model="$parent[field.field_name]">
    <br>
</div>
```

Note, that you have to use `$parent` reference because in your case you want to set property of the outer scope (where `objArray` is defined), however `ngRepeat` creates child scopes per iteration, so you need one step up.

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/35hEihmxTdUs6IofHJHn?p=info